# JS codes run twice in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

These codes are in a html page:

```
 $(".link").click(function() {
    alert('hey you');
 });
 $(".link").click(function() {
    alert('hey you');
 });
```

and cause twice alert when .link element is click. Why is it so? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: What exactly did you expect? I mean when you're attaching two events, shouldn't you, according to the logic, get two events fired?

Comment: Why do you need same function twice?

Comment: First of all, why is two events of the same type is attached?

Comment: simple you have call multiple time...

Comment: yes because there are  multiple click handlers registered for the .link elements

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I have a PHP widget that create some JS codes for its component. If this widget use multiple times on the page, the JS codes are added multiple times too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `off()`.

```js
$(".link").off().on("click", function() {
  alert('hey you');
});
$(".link").off().on("click", function() {
  alert('hey you');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='link'>Test</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code snippet will give you an ideas whats happening and how can you avoid this. As whenever you code executes it registeres a click handler on the element. So you need to make sure that happens only once. Or you need to remove the existing handlers and the register a new one.

[.off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) and [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) see for more details

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".link").click(function() {
    alert('hey you');
  });
  $(".link").click(function() {
    alert('hey you 1');
  });

  $(".link2").click(function() {
    alert('hey you 1');
  });

  $(".link3").off().on("click", function() {
    alert('hey you 3');
  });
  $(".link3").off().on("click", function() {
    alert('hey you 4');
  });
  $(".link3").off().on("click", function() {
    alert('hey you 5');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link">Link1</button>

<button class="link2">Link2</button>

<button class="link3">Link3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like ajax loader, and want to attach event to newly loaded elements, you can mark the already attached elements so that when you next attach it, you don't re-attach the function.

like this:

```
function attachEvent(){
    $('.class-selector:not(.marked)')  // only select element that have not been attached
         .addClass('marked')           // mark it as attached
         .on('click', someFunction);   // attach the event
}

function someFunction(){
    alert('hohoho');
}

function loadAjax(){
    $.ajax({url: 'some-url', success: function(){
         // add newly loaded element here
         // attach event to them
         attachEvent();
    });
}
```

of-course you can use detach and re-attach approach, but this might cause problem when you need to have multiple events on the element